# Embedding Stackblitz Editor on Medium

Tags: angular, typescript, medium-editor, medium.com-publishing-api, stackblitz

I [wrote this article](https://medium.com/@ole.ersoy/proxying-file-upload-buttons-with-angular-a5a3fc224c38) and I'm attempting to embed the corresponding Stackblitz example.

I click on share and select `preview only` and then paste the link into medium:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/html5-file-api2?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts&view=preview

It does not render the editor so that the code is visible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just using this would work:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/html5-file-api2
```

Get rid of the rest.

Here's a [**Draft Link**](https://medium.com/@siddajmera/-a4b5525355ce) to the preview.